# Can't move async functions to Appium PageObjects

Tags: javascript, appium, pageobjects

When the function is defined like this, everything works and my test successfully clicks the button (code here is simplified and not copy pasted, so if there are any syntax errors in ticket description, it's not the answer to ticket):

```
    const wdio = require("webdriverio");
    const options = require('./android.conf.js').config;

    describe('Main',async ()=> {
      it('Should click button', async ()=> {
        const client = await wdio.remote(options);
        const button = await client.findElement('id', 'app.debug:id/theID');
        await client.isElementDisplayed(button.ELEMENT).then(async () => {
          await client.elementClick(button.ELEMENT);
     })
})
```

But I describe the pageObject like this:

```
  function PageObjects() {

    this.clickButton = async (client)=> {
            const button = await client.findElement('id', 'app.debug:id/theID');
            await client.isElementDisplayed(button.ELEMENT).then(async () => {
              await client.elementClick(button.ELEMENT);
            });
    }
  };
    module.exports = PageObjects;
```

And my function like this:

```
    const wdio = require("webdriverio");
const options = require('./android.conf.js').config;
   const PageObjects = require('./po.js');

   describe('Main', async ()=> {
      const po = new PageObjects();
     it('Should click button', async ()=> {
       const client = await wdio.remote(options);
       po.clickButton(client);
      })
    })
```

It stops working and my test cannot click the button anymore! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently since this is an async flow, `po.clickButton()`tries to be executed faster than wdio driver is described. To prevent that, `await` needs to be added so all the test steps are executed in correct order:

```
     describe('Main', async ()=> {
       const po = new PageObjects();
       it('Should click button', async ()=> {
         const client = await wdio.remote(options);
         await po.clickButton(client);
       })
     })
```